# How to clean filter modules?

Tags: jspresso

In my application, users are accessing data that are specific to a station.

Because a user is able to switch from a station to another one, I would like to clean filter modules every time the current station is changed.

Icing on the cake, I would like to warn the user if exist some updates unsaved.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to chain a ***reset all filter modules*** action to the one that allows the user to switch its station.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in action that restarts all the application filter modules, but it would not be much complicated to write one. The idea would be to iterate through all the workspace / modules hierarchy and to restart each module.

In order to restart a module, you can have a look to the standard `org.jspresso.framework.application.frontend.action.module.ModuleRestartAction` (source [here](https://github.com/jspresso/jspresso-ce/blob/master/application/src/main/java/org/jspresso/framework/application/frontend/action/module/ModuleRestartAction.java)). You could even inherit this action and simply override the `execute` method in order to deal with all the application modules instead of only the selected one.

Of course, if you feel like it could be a good addition  to the framework standards, feel free to submit a RFE or even a PR.